# How to fix property '_doc' does not exist on type 'IUser & { _id: any; }'?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm creating a GraphQL api that is connected to MongoDB. I'm currently trying to make a resolver query for the type User but I'm getting an error when I call _doc, I know I can just add a _doc property to the type IUser (code below) but I don't know what type that would be and how it'd affect my database model for User. The error is in the resolver code below, and I'll also attach the interface and schema code below.

**Error in line 10, when calling ...r._doc**

```
import User from '../models/User'
import { GraphQLResolveInfo } from 'graphql'

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users (parent: any, args: any, context: any, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) {
      return User.find()
        .then (user => {
          return user.map (r => ({
            ...r._doc
          }))
        })
    }
  }
}
```

**IUser Interface**

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  name?: string;
  university?: string;
  degree?: string;
  startYear?: number;
  endYear?: number;
};
```

**User Schema**

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'
import { IUser } from '../interfaces/IUser'

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: String,
  university: String,
  degree: String,
  startYear: {
    type: Number,
    default: 2021,
  },
  endYear: {
    type: Number,
    default: 2025
  },
});

const User = model<IUser>('User', userSchema)

export default User;
```